# How to call an observer from custom module: Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, event-observer

I built a custom module which has a custom observer `OrderSaveAfter.php`. How can I call any function inside the custom observer from another custom code ?

Comment: When You Want To call Observer @Jsparo30

Comment: let me know whether u would like to save any data in sales_order table?

Comment: please let me know u r comments whether it is working or not ?

Comment: @PranayK, for a special case I built custom php code under Magento root, so i need to call observer from it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an event called **checkout_onepage_controller_success_action**

Please follow the below steps

**Step 1**: **app/code/Ewall/Paytrade/etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
       <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
           <observer name="Ewall_Paytrade_After_Place_Order_Success" instance="Namespace\Module\Observer\AfterOrder"  />
       </event>
    </config>
```

**Step 2:**

```
<?php
 namespace Ewall\Paytrade\Observer;
 use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
 use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
 use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
class PlaceOrderSuccess implements ObserverInterface
{ 

    protected $orderRepository;
    protected $_session;

    public function __construct(  
    OrderRepositoryInterface $OrderRepositoryInterface,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session
    ) {
        $this->orderRepository = $OrderRepositoryInterface;
        $this->_session = $session;

    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) 
    {

           $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP.'/var/log/TradeorderSuccess.log');
           $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
           $logger->addWriter($writer);            

           $order_ids = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds()[0];
           $order = $this->orderRepository->get($order_ids);           
           $order_id = $order->getIncrementId();               

          foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item)
          {
                $logger->info("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx===>".$item->getName());
           } 

          $order->save();
          $logger->info("saved");
    }


}
```

**Step 3:** after did the changes use di.compile and clear cache & pagecache and and check the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But how can i call a specific custom observer ?

Answer (score 0):

At the end, your observer is a class. So, I believe you could try to inject it in any other class constructor, and so call any method you want

```
<?php
namespace YourNamespace\YourModuleName\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class YourObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
...
```

So, in any of your classes

```
protected $_observer;

public function __construct(
    \YourNamespace\YourModuleName\Observer\YourObserver $observer
) {
    $this->_observer = $observer;
}
```

Although, considering you cannot define which concrete method to be executed in your events xml file (as we did in Magento 1), I would say this could be not a good practice

I can't find any reason why you'd have some public methods in your observer. In that case maybe you'll want to move it to a helper or any other class in your custom module, and then inject that class in observer's constructor if you need to call them during `execute()` method